# cannot login to admin panel in joomla in local server

Tags: php, joomla

I'm not familiar with Joomla. But I need to add some functionalities in a Joomla project. The site is already live so i just copied all the files from server and saved in my local server and also the database. The live site is running smoothly but when I open the site in local server, it throw an error like `Missing jat3 framework plugin`. I googled for a solution and the required plugin downloaded. But I cannot login into Admin panel to install the plugin. 
There is no error, but it just redirect to `administrator/index.php` page when I submit the login page. I don't know why this is happening. Someone please help me to find out the solution.

This is my configuration.php file

```
<?php
class JConfig {
    public $offline = '0';
    public $offline_message = 'This site is down for maintenance.<br /> Please check back again soon.';
    public $display_offline_message = '1';
    public $offline_image = '';
    public $sitename = 'xxxxxx';
    public $editor = 'tinymce';
    public $captcha = '0';
    public $list_limit = '20';
    public $access = '1';
    public $debug = '0';
    public $debug_lang = '0';
    public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = '';
    public $db = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    public $dbprefix = 'gwh_';
    public $live_site = '';
    public $secret = 'qdG9U31MYMBSUCqC';
    public $gzip = '1';
    public $error_reporting = 'none';
    public $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help{major}{minor}:{keyref}';
    public $ftp_host = '127.0.0.1';
    public $ftp_port = '21';
    public $ftp_user = 'xxxx';
    public $ftp_pass = 'xxxx';
    public $ftp_root = '';
    public $ftp_enable = '0';
    public $offset = 'Asia/Kolkata';
    public $mailer = 'smtp';
    public $mailfrom = 'info@xxxxx.com';
    public $fromname = 'xxxxx';
    public $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    public $smtpauth = '1';
    public $smtpuser = 'smtp@xxxxx.com';
    public $smtppass = 'xxxxx';
    public $smtphost = 'smtp.xxxxx.com';
    public $smtpsecure = 'tls';
    public $smtpport = '25';
    public $caching = '0';
    public $cache_handler = 'apc';
    public $cachetime = '15';
    public $MetaDesc = '';
    public $MetaKeys = '';
    public $MetaTitle = '1';
    public $MetaAuthor = '1';
    public $MetaVersion = '0';
    public $robots = '';
    public $sef = '1';
    public $sef_rewrite = '0';
    public $sef_suffix = '0';
    public $unicodeslugs = '0';
    public $feed_limit = '10';
    public $log_path = '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/logs';
    public $tmp_path = '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs//tmp';
    public $lifetime = '15';
    public $session_handler = 'database';
    public $MetaRights = '';
    public $sitename_pagetitles = '0';
    public $force_ssl = '0';
    public $feed_email = 'author';
    public $cookie_domain = '';
    public $cookie_path = '';
}
```

Comment: I believe you can install this plugin manually, without needing access to the admin panel.

Comment: how can i do this. this is my first time working with joomla or any CMS framework. so i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the $log_path and $tmp_path to your locahost www folder.

For example, mine is (Windows with Wampp):

```
public $log_path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\joomla\\administrator/logs';
public $tmp_path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\joomla/tmp';
```

After that, try also also to delete temp and cache folders.

```
JoomlaPath\cache\(everything inside here)
JoomlaPath\tmp\(everything inside here)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing else going wrong, one of these approaches might help:

You can either copy the plugin-folder into the appropriate place in the Joomla folder structure. Usually `{joomla-root}/plugins/{group}/` you can find the group the plugin belongs to in the plugin's xml file. Look for the attribute `group` in extension-tag.

Or you could go into the database, find the extensions-table and in that table the entry with your plugin's extension key `plg_{name}` the plugin extension key can be found in the xml file as well, look for the `name`-tag. Set the plugin's enabled field to 0 and you should be able to log into the backend again.

Comment: i have jat3 folder in the plugin its path is `D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\plugins\system\jat3`, and the corresponding details in `extensions` table in db. the `enabled` field in the table is 1. so i changed it to 0, but still not working

Comment: then there is something else amiss. Maybe your files/folders have permission problem? It is very hard to tell.